# Регулярное выражение: если строка не начинается с двух и более пробелов?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день!

Есть две строки:

```
Привет!
    Привет!
```

Необходимо обернуть в span содержимое тех строк, которые НЕ начинаются с двух или более пробелов (то-есть без пробелов в начале).

Делаю так:

```
// если строка не начинается с двух и более пробелов, то обернуть её содержимое
preg_replace( "/(?<!^[ ]{2,})([\s\S]*?)(\<br\>)/miu", "<span style=\"color: red;\">$1</span>$2", $match );
```

Не работает. Буду признателен за помощь.

Comment: А что с пробелами делать, оставлять их?

Comment: Просто необходимо полностью обработать только те строки, у которых нет более двух пробелов в начале. Остальные (с пробелами в начале), просто пропустить

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$str="Привет<br>\n  Привет2<br>\n Привет3!<br>";
preg_match_all("/^(?![ ]{2,})([\s\S]*?)(\<br\>)$/miu", $str, $mtc, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($mtc);
?>
```

Дальше уже работать с массивом `$mtc`.

Или, если нужно оставить строки необработанными, а не удалять совсем, тогда:

```
<?php
$str="Привет<br>\n  Привет2<br>\n Привет3!<br>";
echo preg_replace("/^(?![ ]{2,})([\s\S]*?)(\<br\>)$/miu", '<span style=\"color: red;\">$1</span>$2', $str);
?>
```